# Добавление изображение по ссылке в DataGridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

Есть таблица DataGridView, в ней колонка с типом данных DataGridViewImageColumn. Как добавить туда ссылку на изображение, чтобы показать картинку? По типу как в PictureBox: `pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "https://pp.userapi.com/c846217/v846217473/161c49/M5UzhfdLpFE.jpg";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно, задача сводится к 2м простым задачам:

1. подгрузить картинку
   .

   ```
   using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) 
   {
       client.DownloadFile(new Uri(url), @"c:\temp\image35.png");
       //или 
       client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), @"c:\temp\image35.png");
   }
   ```
2. применить картинку в DGV в колонку с картинками

   ```
   dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = Properties.Resources.image01;
   ```

Comment: А если возможность не скачивать фото на компьютер?

Comment: Сохранять на компьютер не обязательно. Скачивать -- обязательно. По другому сделать невозможно.